# high CPU usage of MySQL and recommendation from Mysqltunner

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, cpu, mysqltuner, sysdba

we have noticed that our database server is getting so high CPU (more than 90 % used by mysqld process), the output of mysqltunner is shown below, can you help me please,

i'm okay about the innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=7), but is there some other suggestions ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: High CPU utilisation is often an indicator of poorly tuned queries. "Joins performed without indexes" is a good place to start looking. You're also running short on memory, which I would consider to be a higher priority problem than 90% CPU utilisation.

Comment: where can i find them ?

Comment: cross posted...

Comment: From MySQL Command Prompt, SET GLOBAL log_queries_not_using_indexes=1 for 15 minutes for logging to your Slow Query Log.  Turn back off in 15 minutes with SET GLOBAL log_queries_not_using_indexes=0;. Look at your Slow Query Log. Post on pastebin.com A) your complete MySQLTuner report, B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;, and D) from your OS  report from ulimit -a  for more helpful suggestions.